# Build Tools revision 28.0.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android studio 3.2 installed. I have installed the sdk tools and platform tools manually because I'm in cuba. I really need to download the sdk build tools revision 28.0.2 from another server. Is there is anyway​ to download this from external site? My OS Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can download sdk tools from below link:- 
https://developer.android.com/studio/